# Issue with Fragment slideshow animation

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I am creating auto play slide show animation. In that, its not just slide show, it is overlapping slide show.

Meaning, I have 5 sets of fragments fragA, fragB, fragC, fragD, fragE.

First I want fragA to remain static (no animation to it), it should remain static for 0.5 secs. Afterwhich, fragB should slide in over fragA. Once fragB finishes, fragA should disappear. After 0.5 secs to fragB initiation, fragC should start. Once fragC finishes, fragB should disappear and so on.

I found out that if I add  element in the activity with android:name attribute, the fragA remains static while fragB slides in.

Problem space:

But when fragB finishes sliding in, fragA pops up in the screen and no frag B is seen.

So, I wrote below code in my Fragment B, when animation ends, it should remove fragA from the stack. But when I execute the below code, no animation is happening, Only fragB is shown.

```
@Override
    public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
        if(nextAnim == 0 || !enter) {
            return super.onCreateAnimator(transit, enter, nextAnim);
        }
        Animator animator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(),nextAnim);
        animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(getView(),new XFractionProperty(),1.0f,0.0f);
                objectAnimator.setDuration(1600);
                objectAnimator.setStartDelay(500);
                objectAnimator.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                fm.popBackStack("one",FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

            }
        });
        return animator;
    }
```

I am creating fragments like below,

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        FirstFragment firstFragment = FirstFragment.newInstance("one");
        ft.add(R.id.frame, firstFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack("one");

        ft.commit();

        final SecondFragment secondFragment = SecondFragment.newInstance("second");


        FragmentTransaction ft1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        //ft1.show(firstFragment);
        ft1.replace(R.id.frame, secondFragment);
        ft1.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slideinwithhalfasecdelay, R.anim.slideout);
        //ft1.hide(firstFragment);

        //ft1.addToBackStack("two");

        ft1.addToBackStack("two");
        //ft1.show(secondFragment);
        ft1.commit();
```

My Activity code is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:name="clinicloud.com.slideshowtesting.FirstFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </fragment>


</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Okay, with Hasmukh's suggestion, I modified the code, it worked.

```
FirstFragment firstFragment1 = FirstFragment.newInstance("first");

        Log.d(TAG, "****Adding first fragment");
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        FirstFragment firstFragment = FirstFragment.newInstance("one");
        ft.add(R.id.frame, firstFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack("one");
        ft.commit();

        final SecondFragment secondFragment = SecondFragment.newInstance("second");


        FragmentTransaction ft1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft1.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slideinwithhalfasecdelay, R.anim.slideout);
        ft1.replace(R.id.frame, secondFragment);
        ft1.commit();
```

But now I am trying to add my third fragment,

```
FirstFragment firstFragment1 = FirstFragment.newInstance("first");

        Log.d(TAG, "****Adding first fragment");
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        FirstFragment firstFragment = FirstFragment.newInstance("one");
        ft.add(R.id.frame, firstFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack("one");
        ft.commit();

        final SecondFragment secondFragment = SecondFragment.newInstance("second");


        FragmentTransaction ft1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft1.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slideinwithhalfasecdelay, R.anim.slideout);
        ft1.replace(R.id.frame, secondFragment);
        ft1.commit();

        ThirdFragment thirdFragment = ThirdFragment.newInstance("three");
        FragmentTransaction ft2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft2.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slideinwithasecdelay, R.anim.slideout);
        ft2.replace(R.id.frame, thirdFragment);
        ft2.commit();
```

Now, only my third fragment is sliding over the first. I want the second fragment to slide over the first and third to slide over the second.

What is wrong I am doing in my code?

Comment: Your post is familiar. So at least now, you added code for the animation, that's good. I'll check your code though I don't know too much about animation.

Comment: Pls post the layout for slideinwithhalfasecdelay and slideout. I suspect you're using objectAnimator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do only one change.

Please set custom animation before replace fragment.

```
ft1.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slideinwithhalfasecdelay, R.anim.slideout);

// and then 

ft1.replace(R.id.frame, secondFragment);
```

Not need to hide first fragment. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Yes I am using ObjectAnimator. I try to do various things. Tried ViewPager as well. Slideshow works fine but i need overlapping slideshow behavour

Comment: Hasmukh I tried that as well. Only my second frame is shown. No sliding works.

Comment: Did you remove the fragment transition for first fragment ? Use only one fragment transition for replace fragment. and please update your code with new one so we can more understand about the issue.

Comment: If I use one fragmentTransaction, it gives me an error saying already committed. Can you please tell me how to remove FragmenTransition. Assigning null would do?

Comment: Can you please update you code with this question so i got more idea ?

Comment: I will make changes and update you tomorrow Hasmukh. I already left office. Thanks for your time today :-)

Comment: Hasmukh, I tried this morning. I did try nullifying FragmentTransaction. But did not work. So I removed that null assignment and tried the solution, you provided, it worked. Thanks. But now my challenge is, When add my third fragment (first one static, second one should slide over first, third one slide over second), my second fragment is not coming into visibility, only my third one slides over the first.

Comment: @Geetha currently you are using fragment.replace one by one so you cant able to see second fragment transition. Please use countdown timer for delay between fragment transaction. Refer this link link for countdowntimer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html         Thanks...

Comment: I tried with Timer already, the slideshow works fine but the background is not sync with the slideshow. The background flickers with all the fragments (second, third, fourth and fifth) faster first and then the slideshow happens. Anyhow I will try with this countdown timer and let you know tomorrow. Thanks